# every derived table must have its own alias mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I am running this query on MySQL and it is giving this error:

Every derived table must have its own alias.

```
SELECT MAX (mycount) FROM 
(SELECT CreatedBy,COUNT(CreatedBy) mycount 
FROM audit_csp_evaluation 
GROUP BY CreatedBy);
```

Comment: Well give it one.

Comment: Incidentally, it's a little odd to GROUP BY the thing you're counting.

Comment: @Strawberry, yes, it's odd but has no practical disadvantage, except that the count will be 0 if you have a group where CreatedBy is NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give a name to the table derived from your subquery.

```
SELECT MAX(c.mycount) FROM 
(
 SELECT CreatedBy,COUNT(CreatedBy) mycount 
 FROM audit_csp_evaluation 
 GROUP BY CreatedBy
 )c <---added name here;
```

Comment: Thanks this is working for me.

Answer (score 1):

You have to name the derived table, like this:

```
SELECT MAX(x.mycount) AS max_mycount
FROM 
(
 SELECT CreatedBy
    , COUNT(CreatedBy) AS mycount 
FROM audit_csp_evaluation 
GROUP BY CreatedBy
) x;
```

x is the name I'm giving the derived table.

Comment: Thanks @kjmerf. Please remove Space after MAX. It gives error with space.

Comment: @ManoranjanJena done thanks